# ECS new task dies without logging out anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-code-deploy

So I have an ECS service attached to a EFS access point. I'm deploying a [Nexus](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3) container on ECS fargate (blue/green deployment). I can successfully mount the access point to my task and it is running properly. But the problem starts when I re-run the codedeploy. New task is created with the same task definition but new tasks die right away without evening logging anything out and saying "Essential container in task exited", "Exited with status code 0". I'm guessing it's because of some kind of EFS issue because a computer cannot start if it has some volume problem (analogy) from my understanding. But what I'm confused about is, I'm not sure why I cannot have multiple tasks connected to the same access point.

This is in my task definition.

```
"volumes": [
        {
            "name": "nexus-files",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "<my_efs_id>",
                "rootDirectory": "/",
                "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
                "authorizationConfig": {
                    "accessPointId": "<my_efs_access_point_id>",
                    "iam": "ENABLED"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

And this is my access point settings

```
POSIX user
userID - 0
GroupID - 0
Secondary Group ID - 

Root Directory creation permissions
OwnerUserID - 0
OwnserGroupID - 0
Permissions - 0777
```

Everything is fine in first task. It wrote stuff to that access point and does what I want. The Health and metrics seem to be fine. I honestly don't think that affects the task though.

Am i missing something here?

I've been playing around with my task definition and re-running the codedeploy. The weird part is, if I also kill my running task manually (first task), ECS will automatically create a new one and that one will work. My guess is that, there can only be one ecs task at a time that can connect to that EFS access point? I'm not too sure since I'm new to EFS.

Comment: Your guess about it being the EFS access point is most likely wrong. There can absolutely be more than 1 task connected to the access point at a time. There has to be some difference between the task definition that works, and the one that doesn't. I would take the JSON representation of both tasks (working and not working) and compare them side-by-side.

Comment: @MarkB Yea, I agree. It should be able to be used by more than 1 task. The thing is, they are using the same definition. I'm just rerunning a deployment from codedeploy so it re-deploys with the same task definition number. And that's where my confusion started. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: If the ECS service itself can start the task just fine, but starting the same task via CodeDeploy fails, then you are missing something related to CodeDeploy. Possibly the IAM role CodeDeploy is using is lacking some needed permissions. I guarantee that an EFS access point can be accessed by more than one thing at a time, so I think you are wasting time focusing on the EFS volume.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I'll look more into that as well.